# Copy a file from one location to another in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-copying

I have a list called **fileList** containing thousands of filenames and sizes something like this:

```
['/home/rob/Pictures/some/folder/picture one something.jpg', '143452']
['/home/rob/Pictures/some/other/folder/pictureBlah.jpg', '473642']
['/home/rob/Pictures/folder/blahblahpicture filename.jpg', '345345']
```

I want to copy the files using fileList[0] as the source but to another whole destination.  Something like:

```
copyFile(fileList[0], destinationFolder)
```

and have it copy the file to that location.

When I try this like so:

```
for item in fileList:
    copyfile(item[0], "/Users/username/Desktop/testPhotos")
```

I get an error like the following:

```
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/username/Desktop/testPhotos'
```

What could be something I could look at to get this working? I'm using Python 3 on a Mac and on Linux.

Comment: Looking at the comment of psytho, have a look at the `os` package for path manipulation.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html the `copy` accepts folders as destination

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to give a **full name** of the destination file, not just a folder name.

You can get the file name using `os.path.basename(path)` and then build the destination path using `os.path.join(path, *paths)`

```
for item in fileList:
    filename = os.path.basename(item[0])
    copyfile(item[0], os.path.join("/Users/username/Desktop/testPhotos", filename))
```

Comment: Simple and elegant.  Thank you. It makes perfect sense and the example was excellent. Much appreciated

Answer (score 36):

You could just use the shutil.copy() command:

e.g.

```
    import shutil

    for item in fileList:
        shutil.copy(item[0], "/Users/username/Desktop/testPhotos")
```

[From the Python 3.6.1 documentation.  I tried this and it works.]

Comment: I just realized this was added as a comment above.  Sorry for the duplication.

Comment: this is a more exact answer to the OPs question.

Answer (score 10):

Use `os.path.basename` to get the file name and then use it in destination.

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile


for item in fileList:
    copyfile(item[0], "/Users/username/Desktop/testPhotos/{}".format(os.path.basename(item[0])))
```

Comment: if you use `shutil` why not use `copy` which directly allows to put a directory as destination?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to cut off the file name from the source string and put it behind the destination path, so it is a full file path.